# Single inner join with MAX condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I using SQL Server.

I have:

Table A:

```
    id1   
    1       
    2
```

Table B:

```
    id2     data2
    1       300
    1       400
```

If I will use `INNER JOIN` I'll get:

```
id1 id2 data2
1    1   300
1    1   400
```

But I don't need any duplicates with id1.

I can't use a `LEFT JOIN` because I don't need NULL values (if in table B no id2 = id1).

How can I get only one record like

```
id1 id2 data2
1    1   400
```

Maybe it's possible to use inner join with MAX(data2) function? But I don't know exactly how... And I don't need MAX from all table2, only from strings with id2 = id1 from current record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id1, B.id2, MAX(B.data2)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id1 = B.id2
GROUP BY A.id1, B.id2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just max the data of table 2
Here's how:

```
Select A.id1, A.id2 , max(B.data2) 
From A INNER JOIN B on 
A.id1=B.id2
Group By A.id1
```

Hope it helps!